# How do you keep a ToolStripSplitButton within the bounds of its container

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I am developing a windows forms application with C#

My main form has a toolstrip with a ToolStripSplitButton which is aligned to the right. When the split button is clicked, its menu displays over the edge of the form, unless, the form is too close to the far right hand side of the screen.

I have played with various properties to try and solve this, but without much luck!

Is there anything (maybe even a DllImport), that can force the button's menu to always fold in and towards the form, and never exceed the forms bounds?

Comment: One ugly solution is set `RightToLeft` to `True`, but I can't think of any elegant solution.

Comment: If you set `RightToLeft` for the sub-items to `No`, the text will align left as usual, however the images are on the right...

Comment: @JohnWillemse, Thanks, I'd worked out that RTL worked (and quite rightly as you suggested...kinda ugly), but I had not worked out that you can set RTL on the subitems. Thanks for that! :-)

Comment: @JohnWillemse, The subitems are purely text anyway, so not bothered about how images render.

Comment: @seriesOne You're welcome. If you don't use images, then it's a pretty neat solution :)

Comment: I've added the solution for future users ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As worked out in the comments on the OP, if you don't use images in the sub-items of the ToolStripSplitButton, this is an easy solution:

1) Set the `RightToLeft` property of the ToolStripSplitButton itself to `Yes`

2) Set the `RightToLeft` property of all sub-items to `No` to align the text correctly.